# Deploy Flask app with celery worker on Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, celery

I have a very simple Flask app example which uses a celery worker to process a task asynchronously:

app.py

```
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND']= os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conn_str
celery = make_celery(app)

db.init_app(app)




@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Working"

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    task = reverse.delay("hello")
    return task.id

@celery.task(name='app.reverse')
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

To run it locally, I run celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=INFO
in one terminal, and python app.py in another terminal.

I'm wondering how can I deploy this application on Google Cloud? I don't want to use Task Queues since it is only compatible with Python 2. Is there a good piece of documentation available for doing something like this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App engine task queues is the previous version of [Google Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks), this has full support for App Engine Flex/STD and Python 3.x runtimes.

You need to create a Cloud Task Queue and an App engine service to handle the tasks

Gcloud command to [create](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues) a queue

```
gcloud tasks queues create [QUEUE_ID]
```

**Task handler code**

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/example_task_handler', methods=['POST'])
def example_task_handler():
    """Log the request payload."""
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True) or '(empty payload)'
    print('Received task with payload: {}'.format(payload))
    return 'Printed task payload: {}'.format(payload)
```

**Code to push a task**

```
"""Create a task for a given queue with an arbitrary payload."""

from google.cloud import tasks_v2

client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

# replace with your values.
# project = 'my-project-id'
# queue = 'my-appengine-queue'
# location = 'us-central1'
# payload = 'hello'

parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

# Construct the request body.
task = {
        'app_engine_http_request': {  # Specify the type of request.
            'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
            'relative_uri': '/example_task_handler'
        }
}
if payload is not None:
    # The API expects a payload of type bytes.
    converted_payload = payload.encode()

    # Add the payload to the request.
    task['app_engine_http_request']['body'] = converted_payload

if in_seconds is not None:
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)

    # Add the timestamp to the tasks.
    task['schedule_time'] = timestamp

# Use the client to build and send the task.
response = client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task)

print('Created task {}'.format(response.name))
return response
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
google-cloud-tasks==2.0.0
```

You can check this full example in GCP [Python examples Github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/tasks)